# ExtJS custom gridfilter for datetime

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am making a custom datetime filter, because the datetime filter of Ext is not very nice. I have a datetime field: a datefield and timefield in a fieldcontainer that has value... it works fine.

I extend the `Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter` and build my filter like the date filter.

```
fieldCfg = Ext.apply(me.fieldOpts, {
    xtype: 'datetimefield',
    overflowX: 'visible',
    format:  me.format,
});

fields = {};
for (i = 0, len = me.menuItems.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = me.menuItems[i];
    if (item !== '-') {
        cfg = {
            itemId: 'range-' + item,
            text: me[item + 'Text'],
            menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                plain: true,

                items: [
                    Ext.apply(fieldCfg, {
                        itemId: item,
                        margin: '2 10 2 2',
                        overflowX: 'visible'
                    })
                ],
            }),
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                checkchange: me.onCheckChange,
                render: function (t){
                    var dtf = t.menu.items.items[0];
                    var df = dtf.getDateField();
                    var tf = dtf.getTimeField();
                    df.on("select", me.selectDateEvent, me)
                    tf.on("select", me.selectDateEvent, me)
                },
            }
        };
        item = me.fields[item] = Ext.create('Ext.menu.CheckItem', cfg);
    }
    me.menu.add(item);
}
me.values = {};
```

Here is the function to make value of filter:

```
selectDateEvent: function (t) {
    if(t.ownerCt.getValue() !== undefined){
        var date = Ext.Date.format(t.ownerCt.getValue(), format);
        this.values[t.ownerCt.itemId] = date;
        this.fireEvent('update', this);
        this.onMenuSelect(t.ownerCt, date);
    }
},
```

Here's the code of the other handlers:

```
onCheckChange: function(item, checked) {
    var me = this, 
        picker = item.menu.items.items[0], 
        itemId = picker.itemId, 
        values = me.values;
    if (checked) {
        values[itemId] = picker.getValue();
    } else {
        delete values[itemId]
    }
    me.setActive(me.isActivatable());
    me.fireEvent('update', me);
}

onMenuSelect: function(picker, date) {
    var fields = this.fields, 
        field = this.fields[picker.itemId];
    field.setChecked(true);
    if (field == fields.on) {
        fields.before.setChecked(false, true);
        fields.after.setChecked(false, true);
    } else {
        fields.on.setChecked(false, true);
        if (field == fields.after && this.getFieldValue('before') < date) {
            fields.before.setChecked(false, true);
        } else if (field == fields.before && this.getFieldValue('after') > date) {
            fields.after.setChecked(false, true);
        }
    }
    this.fireEvent('update', this);
    picker.up('menu').hide();
}
```

But it doesn't filter the data of grid. How can I make it to work? What did I wrong?

Comment: Do you have a javascript error, or is there just nothing happening? Do you really extend from `Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter` or `Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateFilter`? It would be simpler to figure out the problem if we had the complete filter class code.

Comment: No error, just nothing happen. I made it like DateFilter, DateFilter is extended from Filter too. `Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateTimeFieldFilter', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter',
    alias: 'gridfilter.datetimefield', ...` Because datetimefield is my custom datetime field.

Comment: What's the code of `onMenuSelect` and `onCheckChange` methods then?

Comment: Here is on pic:
http://szentendre-szinhaz.hu/magan/code1.png

Comment: @Eleanor Add that code to the question. Don't make other people click through and look at a picture of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your store is filtered on the client side, you need to implement the [`validateRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter-method-validateRecord) method.